# jquery append and jquery html not working in IE 7 or 8

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have the following code in an external JavaScript file that is called within `<head>`:

```
function dailyDealWidget() {
    $.getJSON('http://myurlhere.com?_render=json', function(data) {

        $('#dd-thumb').append('<img src="'+data.value.items[0].deals.deal.splashpagemainimage+'" />');
        $('#dd-description').append(data.value.items[0].deals.deal.offer+' from '+data.value.items[0].deals.deal.merchantname);
        $('#dd-value').append('$'+data.value.items[0].deals.deal.productvalue);
        $('#dd-discount').append(data.value.items[0].deals.deal.totaldealcount+'%');
        $('#dd-price').append('$'+data.value.items[0].deals.deal.saleprice);
        $('#dd-sold').append(data.value.items[0].deals.deal.inventorytaken+' Sold');
    }); //End json
}
```

Within `<body>` I have this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">dailyDealWidget()</script>
 <div id="dd-widget"></div>`
    <div id="dd-widget">
        <div id="dd-container">
            <div id="dd-thumb"></div>
            <div id="dd-infobox">
                <div id="dd-description"></div>
                <table width="165px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th>Discount</th>
                        <th>Save</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="dd-value"></td>
                        <td id="dd-discount"></td>
                        <td id="dd-price"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" id="dd-sold"></td>
                    </tr>                    
                </table>   
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div><!--End container-->
    </div><!--End dd-widget-->
```

It appears that `.append()` is not adding the content to the desired locations in IE. I've also tried using `.html()` rather than `.append()` but without any luck.

There are no errors in the console... both in Firebug and in IE's developer tools.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any error, or is it just not adding the elements?

Comment: No sorry, there are no errors. I've updated my post with this info.

Comment: Do you have any other js files that are conflicting jQuery. If so, use "jQuery" instead of "$".

Comment: No I don't have any other jQuery that would conflict with this function but I gave it a shot anyways and it still didin't work.

Comment: Are your `id`s unique?  You are returning an array of items - if you have multiple daily deal widgets you need to use `class`es instead of `id`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.append()` & `.html()` DO work in IE 7 & 8, so this is not the problem. Have you tested to make sure that the callback function for getJSON is actually being called? Have you examined the actual strings being passed to `.append()` prior to trying to perform the append itself?

Try logging something to the console at the beginning of the `$.getJSON` callback function to make sure that's actually running, and then try logging the strings you're passing to the `.append()` functions.

Comment: I ended up having to make a JSONP callback in order for it to work in IE. IE wasn't getting a callback at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try to invoke dailyDealWidget after the page has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Are the DIV appends working and just not the TD appends? if so, try to re-draw the whole TR row into one variable then replace the existing row.